# How to use Object.deliverChangeRecords method in javascript

Tags: javascript, object.observe

I understand how to use `Object.observe()`, and `Object.getNotifier(obj).notify` or `Object.getNotifier(obj).performChange`, but how do I use `Object.deliverChangeRecords()`

Comment: see this post :https://github.com/jdarling/Object.observe/issues/13

Comment: I'm still confused on how the function works? I don't understand what it does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The point of Object.deliverChangeRecords is to get synchronous delivery
>   to the function that is listening to the mutations.

http://www.danyow.net/object-deliverchangerecords/

Here's a running example that demonstrates the sequence of events with and without `deliverChangeRecords`:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');

function runTest(useDeliver) {
  var obj = {};

  output.textContent = '';
 
  function handleChange(records) {
    output.textContent += 'CHANGE DELIVERED\n';
  }
  
  Object.observe(obj, handleChange);
  
  output.textContent += '1\n';
  
  obj.a = 'b';
  
  output.textContent += '2\n';
  
  if (useDeliver) {
    Object.deliverChangeRecords(handleChange);
  }
  
  output.textContent += '3\n';
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="runTest(true)">With deliverChangeRecords</button>
<button onclick="runTest(false)">Without deliverChangeRecords</button>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: The link helped by taking me to the jsbin example, but you're example doesn't really help. I figured it out from the jsbin example. But before I mark it as correct. I would suggest changing your answer to something like the jsbin example for others who come accross this question: http://jsbin.com/qazipicipume/1/edit?js,console

Comment: @Edwin - I've improved the code sample and made it interactive